# AngularJS 400 Bad request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hibernate, resteasy

I'm trying to implement some post functionality in my app.

I have got the following post method:

```
restrictLoginAttemptsFromSingleIp: function (id, userId) {
  var serviceUri = baseServicesUrlService.getBaseServicesUrl() + "/employee-service/restrict-single-ip";
  return $http.post(serviceUri, {restrictLoginAttemptIp: {loginAttemptIds: [id]}, dataOwnerId: userId});
}
```

My server side is using RESTEasy 3.0.4 with Hibernate validation:

```
@POST
@Path("/restrict-single-ip")
public Response RestrictSingleIp(@Valid RestrictLoginAttemptIpRequest requestData, @Context HttpRequest request){
        return Response.status(200).build();
}
```

The `RestrictLoginAttemptIpRequest` class inherits one field (`dataOwnerId`) of type `Long` from `PostBase`:

```
public class RestrictLoginAttemptIpRequest extends PostBase {
    private RestrictLoginAttemptIp restrictLoginAttemptIp;

    public RestrictLoginAttemptIp getRestrictLoginAttemptIp() {
        return restrictLoginAttemptIp;
    }

    public void setRestrictLoginAttemptIp(RestrictLoginAttemptIp restrictLoginAttemptIp) {
        this.restrictLoginAttemptIp = restrictLoginAttemptIp;
    }
}
```

The `RestrictLoginAttemptIp` class:

```
package blah;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import java.util.List;

public class RestrictLoginAttemptIp {
    @NotEmpty(message = "blah")
    private List<Long> loginAttemptIds;

    public List<Long> getLoginAttemptIds() {
        return loginAttemptIds;
    }

    public void setLoginAttemptIds(List<Long> loginAttemptIds) {
        this.loginAttemptIds = loginAttemptIds;
    }
}
```

I get the following data string from the POST request which seems to be ok:

```
{restrictLoginAttemptIp={loginAttemptIds=[328]}, dataOwnerId=8}
```

Can someone please explain me why I get an 400 Bad request error when I invoke that function?

Is this because of Long datatypes? Should I somehow mark them in Javascript to be Longs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after 4 hours I figured out the problem.

The case is, that I'm reading the POST data (solving permission questions) in a security interceptor. Reading POST data in RESTEasy is a little bit tricky. To create a `LinkedHashMap` I use Apache IOUtils (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) like it is figured out in the next code snippet

```
String result = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream());
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object obj = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);
```

I looked up in my AngularJS interceptor (used for example for putting something in the header of every request) and figured out, that the server cannot read the input stream: `java.io.ioexception no content to map to object due to end of input`.

At the end the problem was, that after I once read the `EntityStream` of the `ContainerRequestContext` it became empty. The solution was to repopulate it after reading POST data. Something like this:

```
private LinkedHashMap getPostData(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    Object obj = null;

    try {
        String result = IOUtils.toString(requestContext.getEntityStream());
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        obj = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);

        //IMPORTANT: After you can get the entity stream only once. After reading the entity stream is empty
        //so the JSON parser cannot convert EMPTY entity stream into any object. To avoid strange errors (like 400 Bad Request)
        //you have to convert the string back to input stream and rewrite the empty entity stream.
        InputStream stream = IOUtils.toInputStream(result);
        requestContext.setEntityStream(stream);

        System.out.println(obj);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (LinkedHashMap) obj;
}
```

P. S. `ObjectMapper` comes from Jackson